# Can't boot windows usb-stick with UEFI

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, uefi

I currently have win10 laptop, so i created bootable usb with MediaCreationTool, FAT32.

And when Im trying to boot it from totally clear pc, UEFI doesn't recognize flash. In case if I clear CMOS, it sees this flash as USB 3.0 or UEFI 3.0, Partition 1.

Both doesn't work, because when i go force boot from the usb stick, it looses it after reboot and asks to select proper boot device. To make UEFI see usb-stick again, I have to clear CMOS one more time.

Also, if I pass these steps, windows installer asks for missing media drivers.

Secure and Fast boot disabled, CSM enabled and legacy setting only.

Comment: Why are you enabling CSM, if you want to boot, to a EFI bootable device?  Use Rufus to make the drive instead.

Comment: without access to Rufus, which is Windows & Mac only, what's a good way to create the drive?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a plain USB2.0 flash drive. Many older (and current) UEFI/BIOSes get confused with USB3.0 drives.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with USB 3.0.  Windows 10 fully supports being installed by USB 3.0, and the fact his computer has a USB 3.0 port, means he can boot to one.  HIs problem is he enabled CSM, which is not compatible with UEFI mode, for many reasons which are clear.

Comment: It could be. But read more carefully next time before downvoting. OP says: "UEFI does not recognize flash". UEFI, not WIndows. I didn't say what is supported in Windows or what not. Windows can support anything, but UEFI can be limited.

Comment: The described problem isn't because of USB 3.0, voting is anonymous for a reason, so people don't have to be attacked for issuing a vote.  Please reconsider your stance on calling people out.